# "in back (of)" in American English

Tags: prepositions

Some dictionaries say "in back of" means "behind" in American English, as in "there is a garage **in back of** the house."

There are also dictionaries that say "in back" means "at or in the back", as in "there are three kids sitting **in back**", presumably in reference to a vehicle.

I'm wondering whether "in back" without "of" can mean "behind", as in "can you see the garage in back?".

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: As an American English speaker, I recognize all of your examples, including the last. I think I would be more likely to say "can you see the garage *out* back?", but it is perfectly ordinary to say "I'm going to put the hair in front up, and leave the hair in back down."

Comment: @choster - Thanks, I missed that. Re-reading the question I see that it was made fairly clear there too. Deleted my comments as they really make no sense!

Comment: "In back of" is only used when there is something for "of" to refer to.  You wouldn't say "It's the house with the garage in back of."

Comment: @HotLicks I'm asking about the version without "of", i.e. "can you see the house in back?" or "IT's the house with the garage in back,"

Comment: They are the same phrase.  It's just that one is extended with the "of" prepositional phrase.  If you don't have an object for the preposition you don't use the preposition.

Comment: @HotLicks Your reply is beside the point; I am asking about the meaning of "in back", as opposed to "in back of", not the grammatical properties of the preposition. In fact, any learner of English who has systematically studied English knows perfectly well that prepositions require an object. Such a basic point does not bear mentioning at all.

Comment: @Apollyon -- **They mean the same thing.**  It's just that you tack on "of" if you want to have an object that "back" relates to.  Just like "ahead" and "ahead of", or "king" and "king of".

Comment: According to one dictionary example, which I reproduced in the question and hereby reproduce again, "in back" does not always mean "behind". Consider "There are three kids sitting in back." This refers to children sitting in the back of a car, not behind a car. In view of this fact, how could "in back" and "in back of" mean the same thing?  "In back" could mean 'in  the back", in addition to "behind".

Comment: That's a separate issue.  The meaning of "back" is context-dependent.  "In back of the theater" could mean behind the theater building or simply in the back-most rows of the theater seating area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say "can you see the garage in back?" or "the garage is in back."

It's generally clear from context whether you mean 'behind' or 'in the rear portion' - but not always.  In your example there could be confusion between an attached garage on the back portion of the house vs. a detached garage that is some distance behind the house.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "in back", I have the sense that it's more a shortened version of "in *the* back" – the two are interchangeable.